# retrieving values from array of future objects, std::vector

Tags: c++, multithreading

I'm receiving an error message I have no idea how to respond to. I'm trying to retrieve the values from a vector of future objects and then output them, but I'm having trouble confirming if I'm retrieving the values.

Code:

```
  std::vector<std::future<double>> threadResults;
  int numThreads = 4;
  double output;
  for (int j=0; j<numThreads; j++) {
    threadResults.push_back(std::async(launch::async, someCalculation, array1, array2, dimension));
  }
  for (auto& fut : threadResults) {
    auto output = fut.get();

  }
```

I'm new to using `std::vector`, so I'm unsure of how to use `get()` with it. Some researching brought me to the bottom for-loop, which I'm unsure if it's working. If anyone sees any obvious mistakes, please let me know, but my main concern is how to correctly use `std::vector` with the `future` class.

Here is my error message:

```
/tmp/ccQ19btT.o: In function `std::thread::thread<std::__future_base::_Async_state_impl<std::_Bind_simple<double (*(double*, double*, double*, int))(double*, double*, double*, int)>, double>::_Async_state_impl(std::_Bind_simple<double (*(double*, double*, double*, int))(double*, double*, double*, int)>&&)::{lambda()#1}>(std::__future_base::_Async_state_impl<std::_Bind_simple<double (*(double*, double*, double*, int))(double*, double*, double*, int)>, double>::_Async_state_impl(std::_Bind_simple<double (*(double*, double*, double*, int))(double*, double*, double*, int)>&&)::{lambda()#1}&&)':
nonOptimizedNonThreaded.cpp:(.text._ZNSt6threadC2IZNSt13__future_base17_Async_state_implISt12_Bind_simpleIFPFdPdS4_S4_iES4_S4_S4_iEEdEC4EOS8_EUlvE_IEEEOT_DpOT0_[_ZNSt6threadC5IZNSt13__future_base17_Async_state_implISt12_Bind_simpleIFPFdPdS4_S4_iES4_S4_S4_iEEdEC4EOS8_EUlvE_IEEEOT_DpOT0_]+0x2d): undefined reference to `pthread_create'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Sorry for the long horizontal scroll, let me know if there's a better to format it.

Here is how I'm compiling:

```
g++ threadingVector.cpp -o threadingVector -std=c++0x
```

Comment: I have seen this question before.

Comment: Might have something to do with this part of the error : undefined reference to `pthread_create'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me know if this isn't the right answer, and I shall delete it to avoid confusing other people, but I had the exact same issue yesterday and adding -pthread to the compiler args worked. Try:

```
g++ -pthread threadingVector.cpp -o threadingVector -std=c++0x
```

On different architectures the std::thread & company leave some of the low-level implementation of multi-threading down to the environment, and one popular library that would complete the threading implementation on linux would be pthread.